# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Varien_Profiler'

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I'm getting following error :

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Varien_Profiler' not found in project\app\Mage.php on line 664

Error: Class 'Varien_Profiler' not found in project\app\Mage.php on line 664
```

I'm not getting any idea how to debug this error.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the class file accessibility or the autoload functionality not working correctly. Does `lib/Varien/Profiler.php` exist? Is it readable by your webserver?

Comment: Yes that file was empty due to some PHP/Small.m backdoor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lib/Varien/Profiler.php
```

Above file was missing in project.